# Toolbar with .keyboard Placement Disappears After Tab Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI Toolbar with `.keyboard` Placement Not Appearing Consistently on both Simulator and the Real Device (iPhone 13 Pro)

I am experiencing an issue with SwiftUI's `Toolbar` and `ToolbarItemGroup` when using the `.keyboard` placement. The behavior is inconsistent between running the app via Xcode and directly from the device.

Issue:

When running the code from a real device via Xcode, the toolbar doesn't appear at all.
However, if I run the app directly from the device, the toolbar and the "Done" button do appear initially. But if I select a different tab and then navigate back, the toolbar is no longer visible.
What I've tried:

I have researched extensively and tried various solutions related to this, but none seem to work.
I also tried using NavigationStack, but the issue persists.
If I remove the `NavigationView`  only then it works, but I need it.

Here is the sample code that demonstrates the issue

```
import SwiftUI

class Settings:ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Settings()
    
    @Published var perKmFee: Double
    
    init(perKmFee: Double = 0) {
        self.perKmFee = perKmFee
    }
}

@main
struct ToolbarProblemDemoApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "car.fill")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                
                SettingsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                        Text("Settings")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case price
        case otherPrice
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    @ObservedObject var settings = Settings.shared
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    DemoTextField(value:$settings.perKmFee , title: "Price")
                        .focused($focusedField,equals: .price)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button("Done") {
                        focusedField = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoTextField:View {
    @Binding var value:Double
    let title: String
    private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = false
        formatter.decimalSeparator = Locale.current.decimalSeparator
        formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox {
            TextField("Price", value: $value, formatter:numberFormatter)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        }
    }
}
```

Question:

How can I ensure that the `toolbar` with the "Done" button appears consistently whenever the keyboard is active, regardless of how I run the app or navigate between tabs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was a bug in iOS and it is fixed with iOS 17.1. So if you are having this issue, upgrade to iOS 17.1.